# In Apostrophe cms ,How can i get the list of the specialist whose value corresponding to the country(joinByArray) are same?

Tags: apostrophe-cms

### I have created an apostrophe-piece named Specialists, which contain the data of several specialists. One of the field inside the pieces schema is COUNTRY (name of the countries they visited) which is joined by array . Now how can I get the list of the specialist whose value corresponding to the country are same. ie..How can I get only those specialist who visited India or china for example. [I am using apostrophe as headless]

**My schema look like this:**

```
module.exports = {
  name: 'specialist',
  extend: 'apostrophe-pieces',
  label: 'Specialist',
  restApi:true,
  pluralLabel: 'Specialists',
  addFields: [
    {
      name: 'name',
      label: 'Name',
      type: 'string',
      required: true
    },
    {
      name: 'photo',
      label: 'Photo',
      type: 'singleton',
      widgetType: 'apostrophe-images',
      options: {
        aspectRatio: [ 1, 1 ],
        minSize: [ 300, 300 ],
        limit: 1
      }
    },
    {
      name: 'phoneNumber',
      label: 'Phone Number',
      type: 'integer',
      required: true
    },
    {
      name: 'email',
      label: 'E Mail',
      type: 'email',
      required: true

  }
    {
      name: '_country',
      label: 'Country',
      type: 'joinByOne,
      required: true,
      withType: 'country'
    },
```

Comment: Please include what you have tried so far and more information about the context. Is this in a page? In a widget? What documentation have you referenced already?

Comment: I want to get the list of all specialist whose country chosen as India...where country is a joinbyOne piece inside the  specialist schema .
I use to filter like this "api/v1/specialist?country[]=India ", but didnt work...instead i get all the specialist data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Apostrophe Headless docs have information on configuration to allow [filtering piece GET requests](https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe-headless#filtering-products). You might not need to do much else, but there is [additional docs on setting custom cursors](https://docs.apostrophecms.org/advanced-topics/database/cursors.html#built-in-filters-every-schema-field-gets-one) for filters if you need to.